# Have to find the longest word possible out of a list of given letters PROLOG

Tags: list, prolog

```
:-consult(words.pl). % words is basically a big database of the 
                     % 30.000 most used words in the english language

topsolution([], _, P) :- %basecase, in case the given list of letters is
                         %empty, output no word and give the amount of letters
                         %and call it P
    word(X),             %sees if X is a word
    P = 0.
topsolution(WordList, X, P) :- %Makes the longest word it can out of a list 
                               %of letters and outputs said word as X, and the 
                               %amount of letters it has as P
    Y = 0,                        
    solution(WordList, X, Y), %Determines what words you can make with a given
                              %list of letters and a given length of said word
    Y1 is Y + 1,             
    solution(WordList, X, Y1), %Determines the longest word of Y + 1 
    wordLength(P, X).          %Defines how many letters a word X has and calls that amount P
```

So this is the piece of code that I made to find that word. The only problem I'm struggling with is that I can't find a way to make the recursion stop. Currently if I input:

```
?- topsolution([g,i,g], Word, Y).
```

Prolog outputs this:

```
false
```

Even though it should output:

```
Word = gig 
Y = 3
true
```

I know why it does this. It is because Y will keep increasing by 1, until it reaches Y = 4. Since there are no possible words with 4 letters out of a list consisting of only 3 letters. This obviously fails.

So how would you guys recommend fixing this? How do I basically tell prolog that it should stop if it encounters a case where it cannot output a word?

Comment: Without the code for `solution/3` it's going to be awfully hard to debug this.

Answer (score 1):

You should be extremely suspicious of your base case because of the singleton value warning. It's important for you to treat singletons in Prolog as errors, because they always represent a misunderstanding between you and Prolog.

I think your base case here is wrong. When Prolog fails to make a unification, it will output `false`; this is just what's supposed to happen. If you call `topsolution([g,g,g,g], Word, P)`, it should output `false` rather than saying `P = 0` and nothing about Word. There is no solution. To say `P = 0` is to say "I found a solution of length 0 but I'm not telling you what it is." It would be better to say "I didn't find a solution."

I think you really have two cases:

1. I found a word based on a permutation of the letters I have right here
2. I found a word by trying #1 on a subset of the letters I have right here

Your base case is actually #1: what I have in hand is a permutation of the letters of a word, here's the word:

```
topsolution(Letters, Word, P) :-
    permutation(Letters, WordLetters),  % permute the letters
    atom_chars(Word, WordLetters),      % make a permuted atom
    word(Word),                         % guard: it's a word
    length(Letters, P).                 % what's its length?
```

Then your inductive case is to strip out a letter and try again:

```
topsolution(Letters, Word, P) :-
    select(_, Letters, RemainingLetters),    % remove a letter
    topsolution(RemainingLetters, Word, P).  % try again
```

The recursion will stop when you've entered the second predicate body after exhausting all the permutations, for every letter in the sequence. `select(_, [], _)` is false. So there is no `P = 0` case to worry about here.